# Connect to sql server and do bulk load of data file from Linux server

Tags: sql-server, linux, sqlcmd, bulk-load

**Problem Statement:**
I am trying to Load data file from **Linux- source** to SQL server table- **target (sql server installed Windows server)**.
After many meetings with Microsoft we got resolve the connection issue.

**Connection string:**

```
[]$kinit windowsserverusername (Windows server AD Account) :- After this command system will prompt for password

 []$ sqlcmd -S servername,port -E -C :- After this command system will connect to sql server with ">"
```

```sql
BULK INSERT SQLSCHEMA.dbo.TABLENAME FROM '**/SOURCE/DataFile/INPUT_DATA.txt**' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=',',ROWTERMINATOR='\n');
go
```

And I got the following error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 2
> Cannot bulk load because the file '/SOURCE/DataFile/INPUT_DATA.txt' could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

**Issue:**

Unable to use fetch the source data file path in sql statement. How to use the Linux server data file path in sql statement or in .sql file.

I have save the BULK load sql statement into .sql file and try to run the command & got same above error.

```bash
[]$ sqlcmd -S servername,port -E -C -i INPUTFILE.sql
```

How to use source file Linux path in sql server sql prompt or in .sql file ??

I have tried .py script by following connection string and we got trusted connection/ certificate issue and Microsoft suggested above sqlcmd method.

```
"pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)"
``
```

Comment: The obvious question is to ask, have you checked that the SQL Server service account (`mssql` on Linux) has access to the file `/SOURCE/DataFile/INPUT_DATA.txt`?

Comment: not sure, can you help me how to check that..

Comment: What does `stat /SOURCE/DataFile -c "%G %U %a"`, `stat /SOURCE/DataFile/INPUT_DATA.txt -c "%G %U %a"` and `groups mssql` return?

Comment: [LinuxUser@server DataFile]$ stat /SOURCE/DataFile -c "%G %U %a" 
UNKNOWN LinuxUser 777

Comment: That's 1 of 3 commands, @John ...

Comment: stat /SOURCE/DataFile/INPUT_DATA.txt -c "%G %U %a" UNKNOWN LinuxUser 777

Comment: That's 2... There were 3 commands, @John .

Comment: groups mssql
 groups: mssql: no such user

Comment: There *must* be a user, that's the user that SQL Server runs under on Linux. How are you running the statements if SQL Server isn't installed? Or perhaps, do you think that the path is relative to the host the statements are sent from? That is wrong; the file path is relative to the host running SQL Server.

Comment: Agree, looks like you assumed the file path would be local to the client machine. It's not, it's relative to the server

Comment: Consider that you may be using the wrong tool for the job. `sqlcmd` executes queries on the SQL Server itself. If you want to transfer data from a client computer's file system to the remote SQL Server then you probably want to use the [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) instead.